# Finding cross sectional volume

Tags: volume

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

> Q: A volume is above the area bounded
>   by the curves $y = x^2$ and $y = 1$ in the $xy$-plane. Each $x$ cross
>   section is a rectangle with base touching the ends of the
>   curves and height twice the base. If $0 <  x  < 1$, what is the
>   volume?

This is what i have so far, the $A(x)$ should be equal to $= 2(1-x^2)^2$ but I am not even sure if that is right.

Is that the correct formula? If so, how do I integrate that?

Comment: That is indeed the formula: $A(x)=2(1-x^2)^2$.  Solve the quadratic and integrate the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it right. See the following plot:

[image]
Now, we have $$V=\int_0^1(1-x^2)\times (2\times(1-x^2))dx=2\int_0^1(1-x^2)^2dx\\=2\int_0^1(1-2x^2+x^4)dx=2[x-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{x^5}5]_0^1=2(1-2/3+1/5)-2(0-0+0)$$

Comment: That is really nice hand-work there! +1

Comment: I hope you are well, my friend! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks so much Amy. I 'm Ok. I had a presentation for students of all fields who are studying Physics, Chem and Maths in which I introduced `stack exchange` sites. Also, I got a loan from the university. ;-)

Comment: Wonderful!! Good for you! I am so happy for you! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I think the stuff of the site should give me a bunch of $ cause of this event. A cheque is more acceptable for me. :D

Comment: @Adobe: Thanks Adobe for saying so. :)